# print specific portion of page in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using following code to print specific portion of a page. It works fine in Firefox but not working in Google Chrome and IE. In `print.css` I'm making some portion to display none.

controller
  - community
Themes
  - css
     --- print.css

```
 var prtContent = document.getElementById('detailleft');
        var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'letf=10,top=10,width=600",height="250",toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,status=0');
        WinPrint.document.write("<html><head><LINK rel=\"stylesheet\" type\"text/css\" href=\"/../../Themes/css/print.css\" media=\"print\"><LINK rel=\"stylesheet\" type\"text/css\" href=\"/../../Themes/css/print.css\" media=\"screen\"></head><body>");
        WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
        WinPrint.document.write("</body></html>");
        WinPrint.document.close();
        WinPrint.focus();
        WinPrint.print();
        WinPrint.close();
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: i want to make some portion invisibe, and those css i had written in print.css.But chrome and IE doesn't consider that css, and going to print the whole div

Comment: The first thing I'd question is whether your CSS includes are correct: `\"/../../Themes/css/print.css\"` - this references two directories up from the root of the site, which doesn't make sense. Where are your CSS files relative to your MVC application? A screenshot of your folder structure might help (included in your question).

Comment: I had also tried relative path, and if the problem is just in path than i think fire fox also get that issue.